# Matplotlib on Android (Pydroid)

Tags: android, python-3.x, pydroid

I'm just learning to code. I use Pydroid on my tablet running Android 11.
When I try to save a graphic drawn with plot() method, this IDE proposes to save a file to that directory:

/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/app_HOME.

But I'm not able to find such a directory on my tablet. How can I find it or am I obliged to save files with savefig() method?

Thank you

P.S. Where does savefig() method save figures if I don't precise the path? (it doesn't appear in the same dossier where is my .py file)

Comment: Can you add the code snippet from your IDE where you try to save?

Comment: I try to save it with a menu in the bottom of the graph window, it is the only path where I can save it with that option.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix would be to save the code in a folder inside internal storage. The complicated fix : You need superuser privilege to access /data partition.